# Show that there is an integer $d$ such that $E=\mathbb Q(\sqrt{d})$ where $d$ is not divisible by the square of any prime.

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field, minimal-polynomials

I am working through this problem but seem to have hit a roadblock, can anyone help?

Suppose that $[E:\mathbb{Q}] = 2$. Show that there is an integer $d$ such that $E = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ where $d$ is not divisible by the square of any prime.

Suppose $[E:\mathbb{Q}] = 2$.
Let $\alpha\in E\setminus\mathbb{Q}$, there is also a minimal polynomial of $\deg \alpha\geq 2$ but cannot be more than 2 since
$[E:\mathbb{Q}] = 2 = [E:\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)]$ would cause a contradiction with $[E : \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)]\ge 1$

Therefore $[E : \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)]  = 1$.
$[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) : \mathbb{Q}] = 2$ and $[E : \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)]\Rightarrow E = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$.

Let the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ be equal to $f(x) = x^2 + ax + b - \dfrac12(-a + (\sqrt{a})^2 – 4b)$. Keep in mind that $\frac12(-a + (\sqrt{a})^2 – 4b)=\frac12(-a + (\sqrt{a})^2 – 4b)$.

$a^2 – 4b$ is not a perfect square in $\mathbb{Q}$ because $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) : \mathbb{Q}]=1$ is a contradiction.

As such $(\sqrt{a})^2 – 4b \in E\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) = \mathbb{Q}((\sqrt{a})^2 – 4b)$.

Comment: Your parentheses are wrong. You have $(\sqrt{a})^2-4b$ and it should be $\sqrt{a^2-4b}$. If $p^2|a^2-4b$, write $a^2-4b=p^2q$, then $\sqrt{a^2-4b}=\sqrt{p^2q} = p\sqrt{q}$. So $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a^2-4b}) =\mathbb{Q}(p\sqrt{q})$.

Comment: PS: **Please** [use MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) That error would have been blatantly obvious if you were using it.